# Winforms ToolTip get and change all assigned tooltips

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I'm cycling over my WinForms controls and give their Text and ToolTipText to my Translation service for translation.
Example:

```
        foreach (ToolStripItem item in toolStrip.Items)
        {
            if (item is ToolStripMenuItem)
            {
                item.ToolTipText = Translate(item.ToolTipText);
                item.Text = Translate(item.Text);
            }
        }
```

However, I cannot access tooltips set by using the WinForms ToolTip control.

I see I can cycle over the components. Can I Get and Set their tooltips?

```
    protected void TranslateToolTip(ToolTip toolTip)
    {
        foreach (var component in toolTip.Container.Components)
        { 
            // Doesn't work. No ToolTipText property
            component.ToolTipText = Translate(component.ToolTipText);
        }
    }
```

Can I access the tooltip text directly from the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a tooltip text on all components in your form like `button1` etc. I think you should use something like this:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls) {
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.control, "Your text");
        }
```

That's because ToolTip doesn't have a Text property and it's set like on example above.

See also [ToolTip Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ToolTip.SetToolTip Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ToolTip.GetToolTip Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.gettooltip(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or you can try something like that but not sure if this gonna work:

```
protected void TranslateToolTip(ToolTip toolTip)
{
    foreach (var component in toolTip.Container.Components)
    { 
        // Doesn't work. No ToolTipText property
        // component.ToolTipText = Translate(component.ToolTipText);
           toolTip.SetToolTip(component , (string)Translate(toolTip.GetToolTip(component));
    }
}
```

I don't know what `Translate(component.ToolTipText)` is supposed to return. If it's just translated string, then we don't need the `(string)` part in my exmple.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: Fixed second example to show how to Set and **Get** tooltip text from specific control.

Comment: It is exactly what I need. I'll test it and will mark your answer. `toolTip.SetToolTip(component, Translate(toolTip.GetToolTip(component));`